# How to get two regression lines using qplot

Tags: r, regression, ggplot2

I have this nice script to plot a regression line based on the regression equation, easy to use when you want visible results from multilevel regression analyes.

This works fine for one line in one plot:

```
my_line <- function(x, m, b){ y <- m*x + b; return(y) }  
#the line y = .045x + .018  
sapply(1:10, my_line, m=.045, b=.000)  
# [1]  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22  
x <- -10:10  
library(ggplot2)  
GP <- qplot(x, sapply(x, my_line, m=.045, b=.000), geom='line',
ylim=c(-2,2), xlab='Gratitude', ylab='Positve Affect', main='Gratitude 
associated with Positive Affect')
GP + theme_classic()+geom_line(colour='red4', size=1.5)
```

Now I wanted to add two regression lines to one plot but I don't seem to get this right. Currently I have:

```
line_low <- function(x, m, b){ y <- m*x + b; return(y) }  
line_high <- function(x, m, b){ y <- m*x + b; return(y) }  
#the line low = .128x + -.254  
#the line high = .180 + .104  
sapply(1:10, line_low, m=.128, b=-.254)  
sapply(1:10, line_high, m=.180, b=.104)  
# [1]  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22  
x <- -10:10  
y <- -1:1  
library(ggplot2)  
PMH <- qplot(x, sapply((x, line_low, m=.128, b=-.254),(x, line_high, m=.180, 
b=.104)), 
geom='line', ylim=c(-2,2), ylab='Gratitude', xlab='Positve Affect', 
main='Positive Affect associated with Gratitude')
PMH + theme_classic()+geom_line(colour='red4', size=1.5)
```

This doesn't work though. Anyone a good idea here?

Answer (score 3):

You could pack your data in a data frame, and then use ggplot to create a line for for each corresponding column:

```
my_line <- function(x, m, b){ y <- m*x + b; return(y) }
data <- data.frame(x = -10:10, y1 = my_line(x, .128, .254), y2 = my_line(x, .180, .104))
ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y1)) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2))
```

Comment: I think your code would be clearer if you put the `aes` inside of the `geom` each time.  The code lacks symmetry the way you currently have it written, when the problem is symmetric.